# What are the use cases for using azure service fabric over service bus messaging?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-service-fabric

What are the typical use cases for using azure service fabric over azure service bus messaging? Though azure service bus messaging claims to be AMQP 1.0 compliant, I would still be writing to azure's service bus messaging api. In my view, both are platform as a service (PaaS) solutions. I am more interested in why I would use one over the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are completely different products.

Azure Service Bus is just an umbrella name for several messaging patterns: point-to-point, publish-subscribe, event streams and notifications. It's PaaS and it's globally available for integration of any applications that are connected to the internet. It does not run any custom code of yours.

Service Fabric is a platform to run your custom services on. You develop a service and then host it in a Service Fabric cluster (Azure is the main deployment option, but on-premise is supported as well). Service Fabric then takes care of things like availability, resource monitoring, state management, live updates etc for your services.

Even though a reliable queue is one of the patterns available in Service Fabric, you can't call it directly from outside of the cluster, so it's more of internal mechanism than integration.

Service Bus and Service Fabric can be used together: ASB for data input and output integration based on messaging, and SF as application cluster.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "It does not run any custom code of yours"? The whole point of messaging platform is to write a custom consumer code that acts on the message in the queue. I am confused. Are you saying that custom consumer code that I write is to merely pull the message and pass it onto something else?

Comment: @Rudra Sure. Of course you do write custom code, but it's not hosted in Service Bus, you take care of hosting yourself. SB is a messaging service for your custom consumer.

Comment: Interesting. If I don't want to host my consumer service in service fabric (for argument sake), then what are my choices today in Azure?

Comment: @Rudra Web jobs, Worker roles, VMs - each one of them can talk to Service Bus.